# Heroku uses older Ruby version when running `bundle install`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-2.7

I'm trying to run a Rails app on Ruby 2.7.1 on Heroku. Everything worked fine, then I changed something in my Gemfile to use [Ruby 2.7's numbered parameters](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2020/03/03/ruby-2-7-introduces-numbered-parameters-as-default-block-parameters.html), and now the deploy fails with this error message:

```
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Installing bundler 2.0.2
remote: -----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote:
remote:  !
remote:  !     There was an error parsing your Gemfile, we cannot continue
remote:  !
remote:  !     [!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: Undefined local variable or method `_1' for Gemfile. Bundler cannot continue.
remote:  !
remote:  !     #  from /tmp/build_6681cf5c/Gemfile:22
remote:  !     #  -------------------------------------------
remote:  !     #  dependencies.any? { _1.name == gem_name }
remote:  !     #  -------------------------------------------
remote:  !     . Bundler cannot continue.
```

It works fine locally and I've been using the same code in a few other Rails apps and deployment was never a problem.

Due to the error `Undefined local variable or method '_1' for Gemfile.` I assume a Ruby version < 2.7 is used when running `bundle install`.
The app itself runs fine on Ruby 2.7.1 though:

```
$ heroku run "ruby -v"
Running ruby -v on ⬢ myapp... up, run.7979 (Free)
ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-linux]
```

There are a few other similar questions here on SO, but they all deal with Heroku not respecting the Ruby version set in Gemfile or .ruby-version, which is not the problem for me, just during `bundle install` it seems to use a different Ruby version for some reason...

**Is there any way to debug this further, or force Ruby 2.7 even during `bundle install` on deployment?**

Comment: Perhaps it's a different version of bundler?

Comment: @manuelmeurer dunno but does this help? https://bundler.io/gemfile_ruby.html

Comment: @maxpleaner Indeed Heroku uses Bundler 2.0.2 and I use 2.1.4 locally, but I don't think that's a problem... the error indicates that the numbered params are not recognized, which can't be Bundler's fault. Thanks for the suggestion though! :)

Comment: @weltschmerz Thanks, I already specify `ruby '2.7.1'` in my Gemfile.

Comment: If you ever have doubts about the version that Heroku will use you can find out by running this command locally:

$ bundle platform --ruby https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions

Comment: @Ewerton Thanks, but this also returns "ruby 2.7.1" as it should. Still, it seems that a Ruby version < 2.7 is used during deploy.